Lean4 instance management
I have a group $G$ and $G$-sets $X$ and $Y$.  I would like to let $G$ act on the type $(X\to Y)$ by the usual rule $(g\bullet u)(x)=g\bullet u(g^{-1}\bullet x)$.  I define a MulAction instance as shown below, and I try to persuade Lean to use it (using code which is a fairly direct translation of things that worked correctly in Lean 3).  However, Lean accepts rfl as a proof of smul_map below, which indicates that it is not in fact using my instance.  Instead, it thinks that $(g\bullet u)(x)= g\bullet u(x)$, which suggests that it is using Pi.smul' from Mathlib.GroupTheory.GroupAction.Pi even though I tried to disable that.  The typeclass inference trace is enormous and I have not succeeded in understanding it. What is the recommended approach for this sort of thing?
import Mathlib.GroupTheory.GroupAction.Basic

universe uG uX uY

variable {G : Type uG} [Group G ]
variable {X : Type uX} {Y : Type uY}
variable [MulAction G X] [MulAction G Y]

attribute [-instance] Pi.smul'

@[default_instance 500]
instance map_action : MulAction G (X → Y) := {
 smul := λ g u x => g • (u (g⁻¹ • x)),
 one_smul := λ u => funext $ λ x => by
  change (1 : G) • (u ((1 : G)⁻¹ • x)) = u x
  rw [inv_one, one_smul, one_smul]
 mul_smul := λ a b u => funext $ λ x => by
  change (a * b) • (u _) = a • (b • (u _))
  rw [mul_inv_rev, mul_smul, mul_smul]
}

lemma smul_map (g : G) (u : X → Y) (x : X) :
  (g • u) x = g • (u x) := rfl


A common solution to this problem is to define a type synonym with its own instances. You can find this throughout mathlib, for example with Multiplicative and Additive to switch whether to use a multiplicative or additive notation, or Lex to use a lexicographic order on a type.
Here, I define a type synonym ConjPi for a pi type with a conjugation action:
import Mathlib.GroupTheory.GroupAction.Basic

universe uG uX uY

variable {G : Type uG} [Group G]
variable {X : Type uX} {Y : Type uY}
variable [MulAction G X] [MulAction G Y]

def ConjPi (X : Type uX) (Y : Type uY) := X → Y

instance map_action : MulAction G (ConjPi X Y) := {
 smul := λ g u x => g • (u (g⁻¹ • x)),
 one_smul := λ u => funext $ λ x => by
  change (1 : G) • (u ((1 : G)⁻¹ • x)) = u x
  rw [inv_one, one_smul, one_smul]
 mul_smul := λ a b u => funext $ λ x => by
  change (a * b) • (u _) = a • (b • (u _))
  rw [mul_inv_rev, mul_smul, mul_smul]
}

lemma smul_map (g : G) (u : ConjPi X Y) (x : X) :
  (g • u) x = g • (u (g⁻¹ • x)) := rfl

As another example of a type synonym in mathlib, I'll mention that for a group G, ConjAct G is G itself but acts on G by conjugation. It's conceivable using ConjAct for your action, where you define an action of ConjAct G on X → Y, and the tradeoff is whether you need to be careful to work with ConjAct G or with ConjPi X Y.
Here's another possible design, using the fairly common approach of type synonyms using a custom identity function:
def Conj (α : Type*) := α

instance map_action : MulAction G (Conj (X → Y)) := {
 smul := λ g u x => g • (u (g⁻¹ • x)),
 one_smul := λ u => funext $ λ x => by
  change (1 : G) • (u ((1 : G)⁻¹ • x)) = u x
  rw [inv_one, one_smul, one_smul]
 mul_smul := λ a b u => funext $ λ x => by
  change (a * b) • (u _) = a • (b • (u _))
  rw [mul_inv_rev, mul_smul, mul_smul]
}

lemma smul_map (g : G) (u : Conj (X → Y)) (x : X) :
  (g • u) x = g • (u (g⁻¹ • x)) := rfl

